# Get SqlParameterExpression value inside Translate method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I'm trying to implement a custom IMethodCallTranslator in EF Core 5

Translator:

```cs
public class NpgsqlCustomILikeMethodTranslator : IMethodCallTranslator
{
    private readonly MethodInfo _customILikeMethod = typeof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions)
       .GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions.CustomILike),
                         new[] { typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(string), typeof(string) });

    public SqlExpression Translate(SqlExpression instance,
                                   MethodInfo method,
                                   IReadOnlyList<SqlExpression> arguments,
                                   IDiagnosticsLogger<DbLoggerCategory.Query> logger)
    {
        if (method == _customILikeMethod)
        {
            var pattern = arguments[2];
            if (pattern is SqlParameterExpression patternParameter)
            {
                // Get the value from patternParameter as string
                var patternString = ???;
                
                // Do something with patternString
                patternString = DoWork(patternString);

                // Put changed string as constant
                pattern = new SqlConstantExpression(Expression.Constant(patternString), null); 
            }
            return new PostgresILikeExpression(arguments[1], pattern, null, null);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
var pattern = "%A%";
query = query.Where(u => EF.Functions.CustomILike(u.Name, pattern);
```

Is any way to get my pattern string value "%A%" from Translate method?

Comment: Not sure, that it works, but try to apply `[NotParameterized]` to pattern parameter. In this case, it should create `SqlConstantExpression`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yeap! It work. You saved my day! Thx)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Mb you know, what if I want to translate existing methods like `string.Contains(string)`? I cant put [NotParameterized] attribute to it. Is any way in that case?

Comment: I would suggest to preprocess expression tree and and replace `Contains` with your method which has this attribute. It is not so easy to work with parameter values at this stage.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Mb you write your first comment as Answer and I'l mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get value for `SqlParameterExpression` in `IMethodCallTranslator` implementation. So try to force EF Core to generate `SqlConstantExpression` for such method. It can be done by adding `[NotParameterized]` attribute to the desired function parameter.

```cs
public static bool CustomILike(string str, [NotParameterized] string pattern)
```